# change height and width of dropped element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a drag n drop file in which the user will enter the coordinates like 3*4 when the dropped element is clicked, using scalar factor I get height and width for the element. I want to change the height and width of the dropped element. Can anyone help?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

  var x = null;

  // Make element draggable
  $(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit'
  });

  var i = 1, j = 0;
  var x1, x2, y1, y2, tmp, tmp2;
  var sf = pf; 

  $("#droppable").droppable({

    drop: function(e, ui) {

      var attr = ui.helper.attr('id');  
      if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false) {
        ui.helper.attr('id',"id"+i);
      }  
      tmp = ui.helper.attr('id');
      x = ui.helper.clone().bind("click",'img',function(){

        alert("clicked"+ ui.helper.attr('id') + tmp);
        leftpos = ui.offset.left-210;
        toppos = ui.offset.top;
        var cor = window.prompt("Enter coordinates x1,y1");
        var c = cor.split(',');
        var w = c[0]*sf;
        var h = c[1]*sf;
        w = w/2;
        h = h/2;
        ui.helper.width(leftpos-w);
        ui.helper.height(toppos-h);
      });

      x.draggable({
        helper: 'original',
        containment: '#droppable',
        tolerance: 'fit',
      }); 

      x.appendTo('#droppable');
      ui.helper.remove();
      i++;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I can't create it because the whole code is mixed up.

Comment: @VinitaVaswani: its really difficult to understand what your saying, so could you create a jsfiddle within minimum code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vini30/Lcfeaf23/2/ here is the js fiddle but drag n drop is also not working properly in fiddle.

Comment: I just want to increase the size of the dropped element if its height is 80 and width=150, I want the user to enter the size and the dropped elements size gets changed. ui.helper gets the dropped element i just want to change the size using code from the centre of the element in all 4 sides. @dreamweiver

Comment: @madalin ivascu I just want to change the size of dropped element.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of things which are missing in your code.

- The `click` event handler is a `closure` , which means it would have access to `ui.helper` even though the event handler function is executed outside its defined scope. but to change the width and height, you need to refer to the current event bounded object via `this` keyword.
- variable `pf` is undefined, so I have defined one local variable with the same name.
- With your current logic, the target dropped item looks odd, so I have set the static value of 300 for width and height in below jsfiddle.

**JS CODE:**

```
x= ui.helper.clone().bind("click", 'img', function() {
    //leftpos = ui.helper.offset.left - 210;
    //toppos = ui.helper.offset.top;
    leftpos = ($(this).offset().left) - 210;
    toppos = ($(this).offset().top);
    ...

    //ui.helper.width(leftpos-w);
    //ui.helper.height(toppos-h);
    $(this).width(300);
    $(this).height(300);
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Lcfeaf23/3/)